# Unable to import an API module into a nested component (Vue)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I've been struggling with a very odd bug(?) with regards to importing an API module into a nested component in a Vue app.

This is the simplest I could reduce the issue down to.
https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-tree-fqj7o

Essentially, the `DogsCreate` component renders the `CreateDogsModal`, which is importing the `dogs` module from the API directory.

As you can see, the codesandbox errors out even on the base URL with the error `Cannot read property 'default' of undefined`. If running this code locally not on codesandbox, the base URL renders ok, but if you go to `/dogs/create`, the error then becomes `Failed to resolve component: CreateDogsModal`.

The things I've found that fix this are:

- Commenting out the API import statement in `CreateDogsModal` (not an option for us, we need to be able to create and import API modules)
- Commenting out the `TopNav` component in `main.js` (...also not an option for us)
- Importing the `TopNav` component in `App.vue` with a relative import or `@/components/TopNav.vue` works fine, but strangely importing `CreateDogsModal` and `CreateTemplate` in `DogsCreate.vue` with a relative import or `@/components/[component-name].vue` does not. Also, the latter would be somewhat acceptable as a long-term solution, but I'd prefer the `@/components` shorthand and that still leaves the root cause undetermined.

I'm using the default `vue-cli` webpack configuration and have checked via `vue inspect` that the alias seems to be set properly.

I've been spinning my wheels for a week trying to figure this out and just...cannot. Does anyone have any ideas for what may be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a race condition in Webpack, using parallel builds, but I'm honestly not sure. I can see `CreateDogsModal` being pulled in from two places, starting from `main.js`:

```js
'main.js'
 - import 'App.vue'
   - import '@/components/index.js'
     - import and export 'CreateDogsModal.vue'
 - import 'router/index.js'
   - import '@/views/Dogs/DogsCreate.vue'
     - import '@/components/index.js'
       - import and export 'CreateDogsModal.vue'
```

One workaround is to remove the race by making the `CreateDogsModal` an [async component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Async-Components) in `DogsCreate`:

```js
// DogsCreate.vue
import { defineAsyncComponent } from "vue";
import { CreateTemplate } from "@/components";

export default {
  name: "DogsCreate",
  components: {
    CreateTemplate,
    CreateDogsModal: defineAsyncComponent(() => import("@/components/CreateDogsModal.vue")),
  },
};
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/troubleshooting-import-issue-jhwhl?file=/src/views/Dogs/DogsCreate.vue:247-346)